# Make use of & be appreciated for (using a skill)?

Tags: word-choice, french

In French, one can use the verb **valoriser** while applying for a job, writing a motivation letter etc. when one wants to make use of some particular skills and be appreciated for using them. I have tried to google out its translation - http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=16845 and http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/valoriser - but it seems that the consensus has not been reached.

My current winner is **add value by using my ... skills**. What would your suggestions be?

Comment: Are you looking for an expression to translate 'valoriser' or just to complete your last sentence?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I am looking for the translation. The exact skill is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: The translator I use has an outlier from the routine valorize, glamorize, et al. The outlier is **develop**. Curious about the connection, but it seems to be where Yulia's comments take us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand your question, and I'm not fluent in French, but when I apply for a job **I try to highlight my skills.**

> highlight - "to make or try to make people notice or be aware of (someone or something) : to direct attention to (someone or something)" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/highlight)

"Unfortunately, the media insisted upon **highlighting** his troubled past."

Edit - Or, maybe you're looking for: "valorize" - "I want to **valorize** my skills" (to enhance the value of my skills)

Comment: This probably does not answer my question. When you apply for a job, you can either draw an employer's attention to your skills (by highlighting them) or you can say that you want to make use of this skills, i.e. you almost insist on using them.

Comment: @YuliaV I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you write a sentence and leave blanks for the word you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... "display" or "exhibit" ("my XX ability/skills") might be the best equivalent one-word verbs that don't have too much self-aggrandizement attached to them. "Flaunt" is accurate, I think, but negatively viewed.